# Is it possible to know if the field in Excel is raw value or two numbers added together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

Meaning... I have b5 with value 345,33 and b6 with value 22,00+12,00 which Excel correctly calculates as 34,00 BUT I need to know if the 34 is result of adding or just a plain number like in b5 ? Macros are also fine since functions like number() or isnumber() don't help a lot.

Both numbers are entered by hand and are not result of any other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
=IF(ISNA(FORMULATEXT(A1)),"constant","formula")
```

Understand that can differentiate between numbers and formulas.

Note: If the cell contains `=34` it will show as a formula, and you'd need more sophisticated logic to differentiate between `=34` and `=12+22`  If that might be an issues, use a text splitting formula to ensure there are at least two factors in the formula.

Comment: This would be great, but my Excel is 2010. But. I found a solution using Macros searching for "formulatext". Easy find thanks to your comment and someone else's (who had it deleted)..